# Get listitems according to the index of another list

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a `List<List<string>>` with three nested lists. Now I need to check if `List[1]` equals a certain string and if so, check if the value at this index in `List[2]` has another certain string. If both conditions return true, then I need to get that certain index and get the item of `List[0].`

For example:

```
            var list = Titles[0];
            var list2 = Titles[1];
            var list3 = Titles[2];

            foreach (var item in list2)
            {
                if (item.Contains("Dt."))
                {
                    int idx = list2.IndexOf(item);
                    var value = list3.ElementAt(idx);

                    if (value.Contains("25.04.2017"))
                    {
                        var newList = list.ElementAt(idx);

                    }
                }
            }
```

This approach doesn't seem very efficient in regards to performance, especially if the nested list contains ~9000 items.

I tried to get the result via lambda expressions first, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach either.

What would be the best or most efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Eliminate `ElementAt` with direct access to index. *I believe `ElementAt` iterates over List in order to get i'th element*
- Eliminate usage of `IndexOf` with index provided by `for` loop *I believe `IndexOf` iterates over List in order to find matching element*.

  ```
  var list = Titles[0];
  var list2 = Titles[1];
  var list3 = Titles[2];

  for (int i = 0 ; i < list2.Count; ++ i)
  {
      var item = list2[i];
      if (item.Contains("Dt."))
      {                    
          var value = list3[i];
          if (value.Contains("25.04.2017"))
          {
              var newList = list[i];

          }
       }
  }
  ```

*Note if size of `list2` is greater than size of `list` or `list3` then you potentially get `IndexOutOfRangeException`*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So this would be a little bit more efficient as in my example?

Comment: I think this will give you solid performance improvement, try it out

Answer (score 0):

Lambda equivalent for your code:

```
if(list2.Any(item => item.Contains("Dt.")))
{
    int idx = list2.IndexOf("Dt.");
    if(list3.ElementAt(idx).Contains("25.04.2017"))
    {
        var newList = list.ElementAt(idx);
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as soon as it checks the second condition, since `idx` equals `-1`.

Comment: Here I'd rather need the whole string of that list and not just "Dt.". I guess this is the reason why it passes a negative index.

Comment: Yes, you would need the whole string value to be compared. You will also have to add a check before ElementAt to check whether that list contains that many number of items or not and it will work.

Comment: Would you suggest that the lambda expression would be more efficient compared to @tchelidze's solution or am I just nitpicking?

Comment: If the underlying type of your lists supports random access then ElementAt will internally use [] itself so you need not worry about that. I am not iterating through the list if you see, so it will be faster, you just need to take care whether that index exists or not before accessing the index through either ElementAt or [].

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Since, as you said, this does not iterate the list, does it only return true once and ignores the possibility, that there could be more items which satisfy the condition?

Comment: It will give you the index of the first matched item even if there are multiple that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; ++i)
        {
            var item = list2[i];
            if (item.Contains("Dt."))
            {
                var value = list3[i];
                if (value.Contains("25.04.2017"))
                {
                    var newList = list[i];
                    break; // Break the loop :-)
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Problem is, that there could be more than just one item with this condition, making the break obsolet :P

Comment: ooops....:-)
In that case, loop till the end and add results to another object....
" var newList " must be declared above the for loop and add the results to it

Comment: Yeah, I know :), my original code has newList declared as List<string> and I'm adding the results like so `newList.Add(list[i]);`
I'm just wondering if there would be another ("better") way of doing this, instead of having to loop through the whole list.